# Android TextView doesn't align to RIGHT in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a problem trying to align a view to RIGHT inside a relative layout programmatically:

Here is the xml(i don't ant to change the main layout, i want it linear layout because i'am simulating a problem):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.upf.ctrl_tp2.Main2Activity"
android:orientation="vertical">



</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the mainActivity.java code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout main;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main2);
    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setText("Hello World!");
    txt.setTextSize(20);
    RelativeLayout r = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams laypar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    laypar.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);//seems that this doesn't work ?
    r.setLayoutParams(laypar);
    r.addView(txt);
    main.addView(r);
}}
```

The Result i got:
[image: click to see picture]

What i wanted:
[image: click to see picture]

Comment: you want to align in Relative layout or Linear layout

Comment: use android:gravity="right" for your TextView. Y u need relativelayout

Comment: your textview is inside the relativelayout, right? try setting the `ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT` to the textview, not the view it is in.

Comment: @Keerthivasan I'am trying to align it in relative layout, and relative layout will be added to linear(the main layout) to get the result that is shown in picture above.

Comment: @MakeitSimple no it didn't work

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper use align_parent_right

Comment: @DrNachtschatten yes right its inside the Relative layout as mentioned in the snippet above. I have tried so but it didn't work.

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper updated the answer for your need

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper  check below ans .. you have to change width to match parent   because above layout is linearlayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The align right will not work inside a linear layout.
The layout_gravity will work.

Replace

```
laypar.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);//seems that this doesn't work ?
```

with this

```
laypar.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
```

Comment: This will make all children of that layout  to be aligned with right edge, which is not what OP has asked for (although he hasn't realized it yet). Correct answer seems to be posted by VishnuSP.

Comment: Solved, Thanks!
txt.setLayoutParams(laypar);

Answer (score 1):

Set the `LayoutParam` to the `TextView`.

```
txt.setLayoutParams(laypar);
```

You can also use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true`in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Yes MR. @CrazyDeveloper  all thing looking good only one thing you have to remark .

```
  RelativeLayout r = new RelativeLayout(this);

//  actul issue belove .

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams laypar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

just change it .

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Width is **MATCH_PARENT**  instead of ***WRAP_CONTENT***

Comment: fixed with:
txt.setLayoutParams(laypar);

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_layout);
        TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText("Hello World!");
        txt.setTextSize(20);
        RelativeLayout r = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams laypar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        laypar.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);//seems that this doesn't work ?
        r.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        r.setLayoutParams(laypar);
        r.addView(txt);
        ll_layout.addView(r);
```